# Most efficient way to write multiple txt files from URLs to local files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, url

I'm trying to extract data from multiple txt files attached to a [webpage](https://www.finra.org/finra-data/browse-catalog/short-sale-volume-data/daily-short-sale-volume-files). However I found that I need to select month of interest on the page to return the attached files I desired. For instance, for Apr files, I need to make the selection like below:

[image: month select]

And after changing the month selection, there is no change to the URL so I figured I can't extract the data this way. But I clicked on the txt file and saw that URL follows a certain format. For instance the Apr 29th file's URL is https://cdn.finra.org/equity/regsho/daily/CNMSshvol20220429.txt

the Apr 28th file's URL is
https://cdn.finra.org/equity/regsho/daily/CNMSshvol20220428.txt

Therefore I figured I could just loop through the URLs changing the dates each time. The code I assembled through reading multiple pertinent SO posts is:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

header= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) ' 
      'AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
      'Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
      'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
      'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

target_url = 'https://cdn.finra.org/equity/regsho/daily/CNMSshvol20220429.txt'

#adding headers to avoid HTTP error
req = urllib.request.Request(url=target_url, headers=header) 
page = urlopen(req)

floc = r"C:\Users\BL\Data\sample.txt"
file = open(floc,"wb")
for line in page:
    file.write(line)
file.close()
```

The code I am using to read the written txt file:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(floc, sep= '|')
```

However, even reading and writing one txt file took a long time. I wonder how I could optimize this process. My ultimate goal is to sum the columns in all Apr files together.

Comment: One improvement would be to write the whole content at once with `file.write(page.read())` instead of looping over each line.

Comment: There are three parts here -- fetching the file from the server, saving it to a local file, and reading that file into a csv.  Have you timed each part separately?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks John. Would you mind elaborating on that a bit: I'm reading one page/file at a time, storing the data in a variable. How can I save all the text files in one variable and write them all at once? Thanks. Edit after seeing your new comment: good question, I indeed did not.

Comment: I didn't mean to write all the files at once; I meant to write the full content of a single file all at once, instead of the line-by-line loop you have now.

Comment: @JohnGordon Ah got it. Just tried it and it was almost instantaneous! I used `file.writelines(page)`. Was that the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have server latency. You can also write all in once as previously said.